# Netbeans plugin sourcefolder

Tags: plugins, netbeans

I recently started a Netbeans plugin, more a file wizard, the problem is I need to know the project source folder, for some reason I can't figure out how to get it.

I can get the project folder, but this can differ from the source folder e.g:

```
Project project = Templates.getProject(wizard);
project.getProjectDirectory().getPath();
```

Any ideas on how to get the real source folder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, eventually it was as straightforwarded as I expected it to be:

```
FileObject pkg = Templates.getTargetFolder(wizard);
```

and

```
pkg.getPath()
```

contains the root folder for your sources.